# Why can't I convert .pem to .p12 file without splitting it?

Tags: openssl, pem, p12

I was looking for a simple way to convert .pem file that has both certificate and private key to p12.
I wanted this command to work:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -in certificate.pem
```

but it hangs.
Every other example shows that -inkey parameter is expected, but the key is already inside .pem file. Is it because developers didn't bother to handle this case, or do I do something wrong?

Comment: This is not about programming or development and thus offtopic, but: that command definitely does work for both cert(s) and privatekey in an `-in` file (though not always for OS-default stdin if you omit both `-in -inkey`). It should be prompting you for the input password (if any) and the 'export' (output) password (twice); if not something is wrong. Are you by any chance using the git4win aka 'git-bash' build of openssl? We have had reports of that being unable to read passwords; if so specifying on the command line like `-passin pass:FRED -passout pass:WILMA` should work.